# Why was my puzzle deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have a puzzle (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36205/dont-press-me-right-here) that received several downvotes. Other users posted comments that said the answer to the puzzle was too obvious, so I tried my best to improve it my making the solution more subtle. But unfortunately the question was deleted by a moderator shortly afterwards.

I'm not sure why the puzzle was deleted. Is the answer still to obvious, or was the reason for deletion the solution to the puzzle (the answer to my puzzle was "a downvote button on Stack Exchange")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't a riddle. It was a plain description of an object. That's not on-topic for the site.

(Also, you bolded punctuation for some reason?)